# Why is my simple Angular app deployed to openshift origin not being served?

Tags: angular, openshift-origin

I created a simple Angular (not AngularJS) app using the cli and checked it into our private GitHub repo.  I created a project in Openshift Origin running on my Windows 10 box, pointed to the angular app, and got it deployed to the NodeJS builder image - the pod is up and running.  The build logs show no errors.

**Here's the problem.**  When i click the link that openshift defines for me to be the external route, I get an "Application is not available" message on the screen (see below).

[openshift app not available message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbFtb.png)

I don't know why the app is not being served.  I'm thinking there must be something special that needs to be done to prepare the Angular app to run on openshift, but I have been unable to tease out enough information from this site or other places to recognize what the solution is - most likely due to the fact that this is my first time trying to deploy an Angular app to a prod-like enviroment.

I am obviously missing something trying to deploy this simple angular app to openshift.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: did you build the app using ng build command?

Comment: What OpenShift environment are you using? If using Online Starter, there are currently issues which can mean routes don't get setup promptly. https://status.starter.openshift.com/ Changes are starting to be rolled out to some environments to try and address the issues.

Comment: In the standalone project, the scripts section of the package.json uses 'ng build', but I actually modified it before checking in to 'ng build --prod'.  But I simply checked the project into our git repo.  I did not pre-build it.  Isn't that an advantage that openshift's S2I confers?

Comment: What port do you have your nodejs server listening on? It should be port 8080.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I'm using Openshift Origin via a local minishift.  I hope that's what you mean (I specified openshift origin in my original post).

Comment: It looks like the screenshot image I tried to include is not showing up.  Here's the text that is in the message I receive when i try to navigate to the external route:    

Application is not available
The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.
Possible reasons you are seeing this page:

Comment: The message isn't important. What port and network interface are you listening on? If you get an interactive terminal in container using ``oc rsh`` or via web console, does ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080`` work?

Comment: As well as listening on port 8080, you should be accepting requests on ``0.0.0.0`` interface, not ``127.0.0.1`` or anything else.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i had also tried using "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0" in the scripts section in package.json.  Same result.  I will work on getting the interactive terminal in the container.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Graham, I made sure I have a single pod running my sample angular app, and found the hostname as 'angular-sample-1-15mm5'.  `curl angular-sample-1-15mm5:8080` results in:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to angular-sample-1-15mm5:8080; Connection refused.`

Comment: Where are you running curl from? I said to do it from shell inside the running container using ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080``. That ``$HOSTNAME`` environment variable is already set, so you didn't need to work out pod name, which makes me question where you are running ``curl``. All the same, if not accepting connection, then it isn't listening on port 8080. Since you are running ``ng serve -H 0.0.0.0`` look at that programs docs to work out how to tell it to use port 8080, it probably isn't as a default.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks again for your response.  yes, i was running the curl command from inside the running container.  I tried again using `$HOSTNAME` explicitly...same result.  I'll continue with your other suggestions.  many thanks.

Comment: Anyone know of a good tutorial for getting an Angular 5 app deployed to OpenShift?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my issue.  For now, since it's not intended to be a production-ready solution, it is fine.

In package.json, I modified the "start" script to be:

`"start": "ng serve --H 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disable-host-check"`

Currently, my @angular/cli version is 1.4.2, and I'm using the ^4.2.4 @angular packages.

Comment: What was it before? how did this fix the problem?

Comment: @gregswift hi greg - the differences are the --port 8080 and  --disable-host-check.  Either way, being fairly new to both Angular and containerized deployment with Openshift, I'm getting the impression that  the preferred best practice for deploying an Angular app is to do the build first, then move the contents of the /dist folder to the web server.  I wanted to rely on the S2I feature of openshift, but since Angular can be served as static content, this may be the way to go.  I also understand that using the --disable-host-check could be a security issue, depending on your environment.